# Apache shows "Index of /" instead of wordpress site. Editing DocumentRoot breaks site and wordpress login

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

I can click the folder called "wordpress" in the 'index of/' page and it will take me to my site.

I tried using:

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

and editing

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress`

But this appears to break my site. I don't mind remaking the site on wordpress since it's only a starter template for now. But the issue is, after I make this change, I'm no longer able to log into wordpress using "/wp-admin" at the end of my domain. Rather, I get a 404 error page.

Any ideas?

edit:

Here's the contenet of `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4'''
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the entire content of your `000-default.conf` file? It would be better if people didn't have to guess at your Apache configuration. Could you also confirm whether your WordPress installation is located in `/var/www/wordpress` or `/var/www/html/wordpress`?

Comment: Have just edited it to include the content of ```000-default.conf```, Matigo.

Wordpress is installed in ```/var/www/html/wordpress```

Comment: Looking at your configuration file, your `DocumentRoot` is not set as `/var/www/html/wordpress`. Once you change it, do not forget to reload Apache. The best way to do this is with an Apache restart: `sudo service apache2 restart`. Once done, you should see things are operating mostly correctly.

Comment: I tried this. This is what I meant in my title when I said editing DocumentRoot broke the site. The site barely loads and all the text and images are completely jumbled. Worse still, when I try to log in to wordpress using wp-admin, I get a 404 error and it's inaccessible.

At this point I'm considering completely wiping the server and starting again from scratch. But would love a solution.

Comment: Question: Have you used your WordPress installation while it was set to {your domain}/wordpress? If so, then the WordPress configuration itself is what's "breaking" your site, as that software is rather stubborn once installed. You can fix it, of course, but it means you need to be comfortable with going into your database and issuing manual `UPDATE` statements to correct various bits of metadata ...

Comment: Hmm, is there an easier way to do it? What about deleting and reinstalling wordpress somehow?

I don't mind deleting the site and starting from scratch, since it was just the starter template that is set up currently.

If this is an option, any guidance of how I would do that? Thanks, I really appreciate your help so far Matigo

Comment: If you do not care one bit about your current WordPress database, then simply make a new one. This can be done by dropping and recreating, or simply making a new one and updating `wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I stumbled upon this thread. It gave me a hint.

The problem is about the wordpress configuration.

First you must keep the configuration for domain.com/wordpress

Then enter the wordpress dashboard by using that url.

Go to settings

Remove the wordpress suffix from the url in the wordpress adress and site adress

now change the settings at 000-default.conf as you said and change the documentroot.

Restart apache

Voila!

The problem is even tho you change the root folder wordpress is configured to use domain.com/wordpress and looking for all the files in that path